# External CSS won't work in Chrome

Tags: html, css

Complete and total noob here. My external style sheet works perfectly fine in IE9, but won't work at all in Chrome. Here's the HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />
</head>

<title>DCE</title>

</head>

<body>

<a href="index.html">
<img src="Images\logo.png" alt="Logo" width="50%" height="50%">
</a> 

<br>

<hr style="height:5px">
<embed height="50" width="100" src="Theme.mp3">

<ul>ABC
<a href="pages\aboutus.html"><li>Z</li></a> 
<a href="pages\AAAA.html"><li>Y</li></a> 
</ul>

<h2>X</h2>

<p>Blah</p>
<p>Blah</p>


</body>

</html>
```

And the horrifically terrible CSS.

```
h1 {color:#e03d89;}
body {background-image:url(Images/Background.png);}
h2 {font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;}
p {font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
a:link {color:#e03d89;}     
a:visited {color:#e97fa5;}  
a:hover {color:#eb0258;}  
a:active {color:#7a0453;}  
p {margin-left: 30px; text-indent: 20px}
h2 {color:#e03d89;}
h2 {text-align:center}
```

Thanks for any help you guys can give. I'm sure I've done something horribly wrong in posting this and all I can do is hope you all will forgive me.

Comment: What 'doesn't work' about it?

Comment: Check the chrome Javascript Console for any errors regading the css file. Also, try adding the `type` attribute to the `meta` tag with value `text/css`.

Comment: You are closing two header tags, and for you `<ul>` wrap the `<a>` inside of the `<li>` instead of the other way around.

Comment: You know, this site isn't fully of wolves vying to tear apart questions that aren't absolutely brilliant.  We hate laziness, ignorance is expected... otherwise there wouldn't be an option to ask questions.

Comment: A good starting point is to make sure your documents validate:  http://validator.w3.org/ and http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.  Generally speaking, people don't like music on webpages.  You have your slashes going the wrong direction in your links.  `br`s typically shouldn't be used that way, use block level elements (which typically have margins on them) to contain your inline elements (hint: images are allowed within headline tags).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple big things that are probably tripping up Chrome:

You have two closing tags for head and the first one is causing the title tag to be outside of the head.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css" />
</head>  <!--  REMOVE THIS CLOSING HEAD!! -->

<title>DCE</title>

</head>
```

In your UL and LI tags, you can't have text or elements outside of the li tags, your anchor tags "a" and the text ABC need to be changed.

```
    <ul>ABC <!-- REMOVE ABC -->
    <a href="pages\aboutus.html"><li>Z</li></a> <!-- anchor tags outside of the li tag -->
    <li><a href="pages\AAAA.html">Y</a></li> <!-- anchor tags INSIDE of li tag - this is the way to do it -->
</ul>
```

Like @cimmanon said, the slashes in your html links are back slashes and they should be forward slashes "pages/AAAA.html" instead of "pages\AAAA.html".

Those three changes will probably get your style sheet back up and running.  I can tell you're learning/experimenting so I won't go overboard correcting the rest, keep learning and you'll get there :)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what Allen said...

1) The  is the html start tag, so you don't need the addition 
2) Elements that don't have a second closing tag, end with /> like  (this applies to embed, br, hr and img.  I don't know if that would break anything but it's best to do things right anyway.
3) And put a type="text/css" in the stylesheet link tag.